# Passing null value as nullable decimal property to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a null value in a JSON object let's say: `{ 'property': null }` to a controller action in ASP.Net MVC but in the action method I see the property gets a zero value instead of null.

What can I do about this?

Comment: make sure you are using a nullable type in the controller action definition. Need to see code to give a more specific solution.

Comment: surely i'm using a nullable decimal type in controller action parameter's property,something like this: public decimal? propertyX { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just dont send that property or delete that in the client-side : `delete x.yourProperty`

for example if you have some .net mvc controller with a nullable property like this:

`public JsonResult SomeAction(decimal? yourProperty){ //your code goes here }`

if in the client-side you call some ajax request with `yourProperty: null` the model binder will set it to 0, like as int or string that will be set to `EmptyString`

so if you want to send it as null you just avoid sending it, or if it's a property that you have set before all you need is to just delete that property: `delete x.yourProperty`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: that is up to author himself to confirm who's answer is right i guess.

Comment: Though i'm not sure this is the best way through it's working fine.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The property on your model should be a nullable decimal if you want this to work:

```
public decimal? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: So it is as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: In this case could you show your full code (stripped from all noise) allowing us to reproduce the problem? Your exact Model declaration, Controller and View.